# How to preserve ReturnUrl query parameter when submiting form

Tags: razor-pages

I'm using cookie based authentication with Razor Pages.
When the user does not have an authentication cookie in the browser and tries to access a razor page with, for exmaple, `https://localhost:8080/admin/protected`
by default the aspnet core framework redirects to the LoginPath specified in `CookieAuthenticationOptions`. If that Url is something like `/login`, then the browser is redirected automatically to `/login?ReturnUrl=%2Fadmin%2Fprotected`

That's perfect. The problem is that I don't know how this is supposed to work later, because if my `/login` razor page submits a form (for example it posts the username and password), the `ReturnUrl` parameter is lost.

What's the "right" way to preserve this? I'm trying to find something in the documentation without success, nor I can find any asp tag helper.

PS: I was following this as a guide: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/335/simple-authentication-in-razor-pages-without-a-database

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a workaround, although it looks "hacky" and I was expecting to have some syntatic sugar from the Razor pages to preserve this ReturnUrl.
In any case, the solution is to include in my form model a field where I will store the `ReturnUrl` query parameter when the page renders (e.g: Get request). For example:

```
public class LoginForm
{
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

and in my razor page code:

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    var nameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.QueryString.Value);
    const string returnUrlKey = "returnUrl";
    var returnUrl = nameValueCollection.Get(returnUrlKey);
    LoginForm.ReturnUrl = returnUrl; //here I save the value on the form
    // do other things
}
```

Now in my razor page I add a hidden field to pass that value back to the server when posting the form. For example:

```
<form method="post">
  <input asp-for="LoginForm.ReturnUrl" type="hidden" />
  <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="Login">Login</button>
</form>
```

And then I can access the original value in

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostLoginAsync()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }
    return Redirect(LoginForm.ReturnUrl);
}
```

Notice that the ReturnUrl value is preserved even if there is a validation error and the `ModelState` is invalid, which is what I want.